# Android - using TextView as a progress indicator

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to do something like this:

```
TextView myStatusLine = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myStatusLine);

myStatusLine.setText("Start Processing");
doLotsOfNumberCrunchingHere()
myStatusLine.setText("Processing Done");
```

but, of course, "Start Processing" never appears.
I tried this:

```
Runnable updateStatus = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myStatusLine.setText("Start Processing");
    }
};
theHandler.post(updateStatus);
doLotsOfNumberCrunchingHere()
myStatusLine.setText("Processing Done");
```

but this time, "Start Processing" is the only thing that shows up.  ("Processing Done" might show up very briefly before that.)

How do I get the UI to show "Start Processing" before the call to doLotsOfNumberCrunchingHere(), and "Processing Done" when it returns?

Comment: Are you doing this on the ui thread? Are you using asyncTasks? Where is this code being used?

Comment: Can you post your doLotsOfNumberCrunchingHere() method please ?

Comment: Does it particularly matter what doLotsOfNumberCrunchingHere() is?  Let's say that it's just `int x = 0; for (int n = 0; n < 10000000; n++) x++; return;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did u try on AsyncTask ?

```
public class advice extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    myStatusLine.setText("Start Processing");
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //your processing
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    myStatusLine.setText("Processing Done");
}}
```

Comment: AsyncTask was exactly what I needed